# Best practice to build a followers/following MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I'm going to build a MySQL database for a social network style site, where users follow other users and then get updates from users their follow.

My DB is composed by one table with users base information:

```
| ID | username | password | email | ... other few columns |
```

The 'ID' is primary and 'username' and 'email' are unique and index.

then I have a table with users feed that should be showed only if another users follow it, 'ID' is always primary:

```
| ID | feed_to_show_in_home |
```

then a table with followers statistics to speed up users profile page:

```
| ID | followers_count | following_count |
```

And at least the real followers net table where are stored who follow who:

```
| ID | following |
```

In this table 'ID' and 'following' are both primary because an user can follow only once another user.

Now I would to ask if my structure is good from performance point of view. I'm worried especially about how to check if an user is following another user, stop following an user, and how to display feeds only if I'm following that specific user.

In any of that cases, the solution I've in mind is to scan always the full table length, but I think that this is not a good choice since this DB is planned to store over then 10,000 users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:  10,000 is so few that any design will be "good enough".

Long answer:  For more scaling, consider the following...

These designs are *usually* bad practice:

- two tables in a 1:1 relationship.
- store something that can be computed.

I say "*usually*" because you are reaching into cases where exceptions are warranted.  But first, let me mention some other schema designs:

```
CREATE TABLE Follow (
    er ...,  -- user id of the the follower
    ed ...,  -- user id of the the followed
    PRIMARY KEY(er, ed),
    INDEX(ed, er)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Follow WHERE ed = ?; -- number of followers for `ed`.
SELECT er FROM Follow WHERE ed = ?  -- list of such followers
(Similarly for the flip direction)
```

Notes:

- No surrogate `AUTO_INCREMENT`, since there is a perfectly good PK.  *And* the queries will run faster, as we will see in a minute.
- Until you have 100K followers, the `COUNT` query is "fast enough" so that you don't need to precompute counts.

If you were to count the number of "Likes", it would be prudent to have a separate table for that frequently updated value.  Such a table would be 1:1 with the User table, thereby violating the first bad practice.  The justification here is to separate the very high *write* activity in Like from the *low*, but important *read* activity in the rest of the "user" info.

Comment: Why don't you like surrogate AUTO_INCREMENT key? It gives order of followers. It helps to write data in sequence without jumping around. Do you think it not worth it?

Comment: @jsHate - I think that laying out the table for the many `SELECTs` that will occur is more useful than worrying about the ine-time `INSERTs`.  Also, when using an auto_inc id, there is often a second lookup to get from the index to the data.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I would prefer graph databases, because the real-world-problem you are trying to solve has a graph as its natural structure.

From a relational point of view, your idea looks good. I'm not quite sure if you already have all relations you need, but with the basic concept you're probably on the right way.

For performance issues you should do some tests with some arbitrary test data and `EXPLAIN` statements ([see this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)). Now you can try setting some indexes on columns you are filtering for and test it again. Which indexes are best to set depends highly on your queries and which indexes better not to set depends on how often or how much you update/insert stuff. There are lots of other articles that explain it better than I do, so you should maybe have a look at some best practices in indexing in general and ask for specific performance problems, when they actually occur.

Comment: Thank you for `EXPLAIN` tip. Do you think that as a starting project it's enough use MySQL instead a graph database?

Comment: Sure. This doesn't really depend on a specific DBMS. I used to love MySQL even in productive environments, but it ignores `CHECK` constraints for example and you have to enforce this manually. So I continuously dropped its usage. It's definitely OK for sketching. For graph databases you would have to get used to other querying languages, like Cypher in neo4j. So you'll face additional efforts when porting from relational to graph.